# Registration process on google page open up on web view in ios?

Tags: ios, web-services, webview

In my app i have a feature of free gift, which is a registration process on google page open up on web view, i have detected when the registration is been done. If a user  with particular device id has already taken that gift, then that particular user should not be able to get that gift even after reinstallation of my application.

Is there any support on iOS, without calling any web-service for this detection.

Comment: you can save in keychain.. it stores value even you remove the app

Comment: Are you using In App purchase?

Comment: No I'm not using In App purchase.

Comment: Thanks for the help keychain worked for me..